# Canopy Clustering Without Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, canopy

I am new to Mahout. I want to run Canopy Clustering on stand alone system without using Hadoop.
Is this possible? If so can you kindly let me know the commands and steps for the same.

Thanks in advance,
Rashmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the code on trunk, seems that Canopy takes a runSequential parameter, setting it to true should do the trick